# How to move cursor/focus to another monitor using keyboard shortcut in KDE?

Tags: kde, window-manager, cursor, kwin

I want to move focus of the cursor/window between monitors through keyboard shortcut in KDE, is it possible? It should be something like ctrl+meta+j/k in awesome wm.